# Use jQuery in a custom Angular 6+ library

Tags: jquery, angular

**EDIT2**
I get the feeling my approach to write an independent angular library for others to use is wrong?
My first thought was writing a npm module but it has to be private and cant be published - would that work / be easy?
Is my approach wrong?

**How do I use jQuery in my Angular 6+ library?**

I created a library with

```
ng generate library nodeeditor --prefix=lib
```

Then added a jQuery npm module to it with

```
cd projects/nodeeditor    
npm i --save jquery
```

But when stating

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
```

in nodeeditor.component.ts
(as I did in Angular projects only when absoloutely necessary)

```
ng build nodeeditor
```

gives me

> BUILD ERROR Cannot call a namespace ('jQuery')

Anyone got any idea?

**EDIT1**
Generated folder structure looks like this

[image: angular library folder structure]

Comment: `import $ from 'jquery';`

or 

`import { $ } from 'jquery';`

or 

`import * as JQuery from 'jquery';`

pick your poison. if this doesn't work, delete the module and add it again.

Comment: import $ from 'jquery'; does not work - testing next

Comment: import { $ } from 'jquery'; also does not work - testing next

Comment: import * as JQuery from 'jquery'; also does not work

but thank you anyway for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install jquery --save
```

.angular-cli.json or angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

Import jquery file module.ts file

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to check jquery included in our application write $ in the browser console

Comment: There is no angular.cli.json / angular.json in the library (which I later intend to distribute without its parent angular project) only in the source app module / angular project

Comment: LOL which angular version are you using?

Comment: Added a picture to show the generated folder structure. Using     "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",

Comment: I can see the angular.json file 3rd after src folder

Comment: Sure there is one in the main angular app but I intend to write a library "nodeeditor" and later only distribute the library that should be completely independent from the project its being used in.
The one you see is from the angular project I run the library in for development.

Comment: I want my library (that is being generated under project folder) to be 100% independent from the angular app it will be used in (as it should be?)

Comment: If this is the wrong approach to write a angular library for others to use then my question is: What is the best / better approach?

Comment: So you can set config according to your environment (development, testing, production)

Comment: Then it would not be independent from the angular app it will be used in right?
The other developer that gets the "nodeeditor" library from me via mail for example does not have this line in his angular.json - so it would then not work for him?

Comment: The one thing you can do is a, add the file but do not push

Comment: You can not separate the file from the framework (any framework)

Comment: How does one then write a 100% independent, private angular / npm / library / functionality for others to use? (if angular libraries are not intended for this).
Ill wait for a second / third source saying the same then I will flag / close my question for I probably intend to do something that has to be done differently.

Comment: I think you need to write a module and inject if the environment is a development
this is the one way you can do the thing you want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192786/discussion-between-parth-raval-and-martin-eckleben).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your import as follows:

`import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: Nope still same sorry. Also I guess I habituated to do it like that because everything else also didnt work in normal Angular projects. Ill check that back.

Comment: I was wrong import * as jQuery from 'jquery'; generally works but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've a way to do this. I know this is a bit late. But it might help some one in need.
I'm able to use the jQuery in my library. Here most of the answers cover how to install jquery / @types in the parent application. That is part of the answer but not all.

Since angular library implementation expect the node modules to be delivered by the parent application, we need to install jQuery / @types at the parent app level and add that to scripts section of the angular.json like mentioned in the most of the answers.

**How to make it work in library then?**

How I approached this is

1. I added the jquery and @types in "peerDependencies" and "devDependencies" of my library "package.json" file.
2. I added the jquery in "umdModuleIds". (I believe this is totally not required. But I added this to make sure, it will not say unknown dependency when try to build).
3. In my library's "tsconfig.lib.json" file I added the "jquery" in the "types" section.

Ref:

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "testing-lib",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^10.0.9",
        "@angular/core": "^10.0.9",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "13.2.1",
        "@angular/material": "^9.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "ckeditor4-angular": "^2.1.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "13.2.1",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "@angular/material": "^9.0.0"
      }
    }
```

**ng-package.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/testing-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "ckeditor4-angular": "ckeditor4-angular",
      "ngx-toastr": "ngx-toastr",
      "bootstrap": "bootstrap",
      "jquery": "jquery",
      "@angular/material": "@angular/material"
    },
    "styleIncludePaths": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.lib.json**

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [
      "jquery"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

After this I build my library and the jQuery started to work.

**Note:** Please make sure your parent app does have jQuery and @types installed.